# Jade template - extends jade template, passing an array

Tags: pug, template-engine

I want to pass array to another template using extends in jade template engine.
For example I'v got file

header.jade

```
block variables
each smth in #{sampleArray}
  div #{smth}
```

main.jade

```
extends header.jade
block variables
- 
  var sampleArray = [
'item'    
]
```